# How would I print two strings mixed with each other?

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm trying to blend two strings together on output using a loop. The two strings can be any length.  If one string is larger than the other then all of the extra characters from the larger string should go to the end of the combined string.

Say I have `String s1 = "hhhh"`, and I have `String s2 = "aaaa"`. How can I make a loop that would print `"hahahaha"`?

Another example would be `String s1 = "bbbbb"` and `String s2 = "ccc"`. I want the output to be `"bcbcbcbb"`.

I have gone ahead and written some code, to showcase what I have done. Here:

```
public class interLeave {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String you = "hhhh";
    String me = "aaaa";

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
      System.out.print( you.charAt(i)); }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
      System.out.print( me.charAt(i)); }
 }
 }
```

Now the only thing is to get the strings to actually interleave, which I have no clue how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the loop you can use:

```
String s1 = "hhhh";
String s2 = "aaaa";

for (int i=0; i<(Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length())); i++){
    if(i < s1.length()){
        System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
    }
    if(i < s2.length()){
        System.out.print(s2.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

What this does is it takes the length of the longest String, and runs the for loop based on that, to make sure all characters are printed. Then, the two if statements go to work. The first 'if' will print the current character of the first string, if it has any left. The second will do the exact same. If one String finishes, its corresponding 'if' statement won't run anymore to avoid an error, and the rest of the other will print.

This will work with all String lengths.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for helping out.